# Is return without value the similar to break in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function showMovie(age) {
  if ( !checkAge(age) ) {
    return;
  }

  alert( "Showing you the movie" ); // (*)
  // ...
}
```

I am learning Javascript and it says that
"A function with an empty return or without it returns undefined". I realized that break has a similar use case as return without value.
The only difference is break doesn't even return undefined. It just doesn't return anything. Am I understanding it right?

Comment: _"The only difference is break doesn't even return undefined."_ That's wrogn. You can't replace `return` with `break`. `break` is only allowed in a loop or switch. `break` ends the loop or switch. `return` ends the function.

Comment: I've marked it as a duplicate of Java question. The answers apply to javascript as well.

Answer (score 1):

`break`/`continue` is only valid for loops to skip iterations, it does not actually returns from function, only `return` terminates execution of function.

```js
function test() {
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i == 5) {
        break;
    }
    
    console.log(i);
  }
  
  return 'Some return value';
}

console.log(test());
```